# Initialzing const array inside a struct in C?

Tags: c, arrays

What's the best way of initialzing a const array inside a struct in C?

```
typedef struct
{
    float coefs[5];

} t_data;

const float ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVE[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

void init(t_data* data)
{
     data->coefs[0] = ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVE[0];
     data->coefs[1] = ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVE[1];
     ...
}
```

In real world I have much more than 5 elements.

Is there some better way?

Comment: Use a `for` loop, or `memcpy`.

Comment: "...initialzing a const array inside a struct in C" - The target array being initialized isn't const; the *source* is.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're sure the sizes will be the same, you can use `memcpy`. I'd also localise the source data as well so it doesn't pollute scope unnecessarily:

```
void init (t_data* data) {
    static const float srcData[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    assert (sizeof(data->coeffs) == sizeof(srcData));
    memcpy (data->coeffs, srcData, sizeof(data->coeffs));
}
```

You'll note I also have an `assert` in there, this will allow you to detect early whether you're building code that vioaltes the assumption that the two arrays are of the same size. This will avoid buffer overruns on either read or write.

Comment: Thanks for the scope awarness.

Comment: You can even make that assert a compile time assert: `int comp_assert[sizeof(data->coeffs) == sizeof(srcData) ? 1 : -1];`

Comment: @selbie +1 for compile time assert, but I would use `static_assert` from standard library if available.

Comment: I think `static_assert` is C++ only?  Does it also exist in C ?

Comment: @selbie In C11, they added `_Static_assert`.

Answer (score 1):

You mean initializing the *non-const* array inside the struct, right?

I think you want this:

```
memcpy(data->coefs, ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVE, sizeof(ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVE));
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. Assuming that your `t_data` may contain more stuff than just array of coefficients, you can use dedicated holder-structure and avoid any loop or `memcpy()`.

```
typedef struct {
    float c[5];
} coef_holder;

static const coef_holder init_set = {
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
};

typedef struct
{
    coef_holder coefs;
    /* more stuff */
} t_data;

void init(t_data* data)
{
     data->coefs = init_set;
     ...
}
```

Also note, this line:

```
data->coefs = init_set;
```

is not an initialization, it is an assignment. Of course on some architectures this assignment may be translated into call to `memcpy()`, but anyway source code looks clearer.

Answer (score -1):

If you can assign entire structure at once, you could create dummy struct and use assignment:

```
t_data const ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVE = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };

void init(t_data* data) {
    *data = ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVE;
```